# Why Moq.SetupGet throws NotSuportedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

`Moq.SetupGet` throws exception.

Why?

How to do it correctly if I do not have a way, how to change the tested Class (I cannot add interface or make the property virtual or stuff like that)

Class

```
public class ToDelete
{
    public int ToDeleteProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Test

```
[TestMethod]
public void PutCaseByIdCaseContactsExperimental()
{
    var toDelete = new Mock<ToDelete>();
    toDelete.SetupGet(x => x.ToDeleteProperty).Returns(5); //<------throws exception below

    Assert.AreEqual(toDelete.Object.ToDeleteProperty, 5);
 }
```

> Result StackTrace:     v Moq.Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method,
>   Expression expression)    v Moq.InvocationShape..ctor(LambdaExpression
>   expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList'1 arguments)    v
>   Moq.ExpressionExtensions.g__Split|4_1(Expression e, Expression&
>   r, InvocationShape& p)    v
>   Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression)    v
>   Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition
>   condition)    v Moq.Mock.SetupGet(Mock mock, LambdaExpression
>   expression, Condition condition)    v
>   Moq.Mock`1.SetupGet[TProperty](Expression`1 expression)    v
>   Cnx.Csm.CaseManagement.Test.Controllers.CaseControllerTest.PutCaseByIdCaseContactsExperimental()
>   v C:\tfs____Test.cs:line 682 Result Message:  Test method
>   ____________________Test._______________ threw exception:  System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: x =>
>   x.ToDeleteProperty Non-overridable members (here:
>   CaseControllerTest.ToDelete.get_ToDeleteProperty) may not be used in
>   setup / verification expressions.

Comment: You don't have to mock `ToDeleteProperty`. Try to constuct a concrete object and set the value to `5` like you would do in non-testing code.

Comment: Why you want to use mock here? Just construct the instance of the object for the test purpose? Or use stub by SetupAllProperties...

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to mock a non-virtual type.

Basically under the hood Moq creates a proxy that implements, inherits from the type that should be mocked and overrides the properties and methods with it's own.

Usually Moq is all about to provide test implementations for `abstract` types, like base classes and interfaces, that cannot or should not be used in the test (for design or simplicity).

You can get your scenario working when you declare your property like this:

```
public virtual int ToDeleteProperty
```

although I would not recommend to change your class this way.